# Проблема при работе с clouser

Tags: swift

Всем привет, есть вот такой код

```
    struct NetworkImageManager {
    func fetchCurrentImage(completionHandler: @escaping (CurrrenImage)-> Void) {
        let urlString = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=\(key)&q&image_type=photo"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { data, responce, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let currentImage = self.parseJSON(withData: data){
                    completionHandler(currentImage)
                }
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJSON(withData data: Data) -> CurrrenImage? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let currentImageData = try decoder.decode(CurrentImageData.self, from: data)
            guard let currentImage = CurrrenImage(currentImageData: currentImageData) else {return nil
            }
            return currentImage
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil

    }

}
```

при попытке предать данные с одного вью на другой выдается следующая ошибка (ошибку описал после //)

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {



let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2
let sectionInserts = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)

let networkImageManager = NetworkImageManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    networkImageManager.fetchCurrentImage(completionHandler: CurrrenImage) // Cannot convert value of type 'CurrrenImage.Type' to expected argument type '(CurrrenImage) -> Void'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ошибке же написано, что передаётся тип в качестве параметра.

Для получения результата:

```swift
networkImageManager.fetchCurrentImage(completionHandler: { image in 
    // Do something with image
})
```

Считайте, что closure – это обычная функция, только без имени, поэтому в `completionHandler` пишется не `CurrrenImage`, а:

```swift
{ image in ... }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Приду попробую